# Cannot access to Laravel register and login views

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, vue.js

Attempting to learn and domain Laravel I developed a website with it 5.6 version and vuejs 2.

In it's admin section I want to implement an authorization system. I tryed with Passport API and axios but I can't achived it. So I undid all I was made and now, I'm trying to implement the Laravel Authorization but I can't access to /login and /register routes. When you go to those urls the page automactically redirects you to home page. I deleted cache and cookies, and the issue persists. I reviewed the auth controllers and services and they are identically to the factory version.

I removed the vue routes to avoid conflicts.

It doesn't matter what path is written in LoginController.php it always redirects to home page. So the problem is not there... any way, I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

Please check `php artisan route:list` to make sure you have the desired routes defined.

Comment: The routes are correctly defined. In fact, the route works. But when you access to /login or /register laravel automatically redirects you to home